# What does "leagues away" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.webnovel.com/book/9795095706003005/26751507756023404/Seized-by-the-System/The-System-is-Fighting-for-Justice-

> Fang Ning’s height was comparable to **his in a fight**, but that body
>   size was **leagues away**.

I don't understand "leagues away". I also think "his in a fight" is strange.

Comment: Your source text appears to be translated from another language, and the result is not very idiomatic English. You shouldn't use this text as a model for your own English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *league* is a distance equal to about 5 km.

*Leagues away* is an idiom meaning "far away" or "very different".

> I also think "his in a fight" is strange.

This part is not particularly fluent English. If we just said

> Fang Ning's height was comparable to his.

It would have a clear meaning: The two characters have roughly equal height. Presumably this is true whether they fight each other or not.

A more idiomatic way of saying what I think the author is trying to say might be

> If it came to a fight, Fang Ning's height was comparable to his, but their builds were leagues apart.

Answer (score 0):

Source - Youdao dictionary.

be in a different league

> to be much better than someone or something else

example

> For most of the match, Brazil were in a different league, and won 4-0.

be out of your league

> to not be skilled or experienced enough to do or deal with something

Comment: The question is about *leagues away*, however, which is a different idiom from these and which uses a different meaning of *league* with a completely different etymology..

Comment: Wrong meaning of "league"